# Weird Firefox behavior with setAttribute('ahref')

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Firefox this code doesn't work (link is hidden):

```
var o = document.getElementById("LinkFBShareLink");
var fbURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + link + '&title=' + title;
o.setAttribute('href', fbURL);
```

whereas this code works:

```
var o = document.getElementById("LinkFBShareLink");
var fbURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.phpu=' + link + '&title=' + title;
o.setAttribute('href', fbURL);
```

(The difference is `?` in first URL.)

The code works in Chrome. Why not in Firefox?

Comment: Define "doesn't work." I very, very much doubt `setAttribute` is broken in Firefox.

Comment: `/sharer.phpu=` is not even valid.

Comment: Link is invisible after setAttribute()

Comment: are you url encoding the values?

Comment: I know, `/sharer.phpu=` is invalid, I'm demonstrating the problem of question mark presence/absence.

Comment: *"Link is invisible after setAttribute()"* No, it isn't: https://jsfiddle.net/ej07sk8z/

Comment: Yes, I do `encodeURIComponent()` on both `link` and `title`.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) that actually demonstrates the problem on Firefox.

Comment: It turns out that adblocker was blocking references to `sharer.php` So correct answer should be: always turn off adblocker before testing your HTML code...

Answer (score 2):

I can see two problems with your code, although I cannot replicate the issue you describe (tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ej07sk8z/)).

1. You're not correctly encoding the `&` in the string, but you're using it as HTML text (the content of attributes is HTML text). I would be very surprised if that were the problem, but it is, technically, wrong.
2. You're not URI-encoding `link` and `title`. *(Or at least, if you are, that's not shown.)*

To deal with #1, I'd set the `href` *property* rather than the attribute, and I'd use `encodeURIComponentn` to deal with the second:

```
var o = document.getElementById("LinkFBShareLink");
o.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' +
         encodeURIComponent(link) +
         '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title);
```

Comment: I do encode both `link` and `title`

Comment: Simple `o.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=');` doesn't work for me either

Comment: @milet: That works just fine on Firefox 50 (and I have no reason to think it wouldn't work in all versions of Firefox): https://jsfiddle.net/ej07sk8z/1/ Again, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) actually demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The fiddle works indeed. Thank you for your help.